# How to find nearest distance from a coordinate point inside a polygon to the edge (border) of the polygon in Python?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

I currently have a dataset with lat and lon coordinates in my first dataframe.

And then I have a shape of a country, Nigeria.

`world_filepath = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')`

`world = gpd.read_file(world_filepath)`

`nigeria = world.loc[world['name'] == 'Nigeria']`

```
pop_est      continent  name    iso_a3  gdp_md_est  geometry
```

56  200963599.0 | Africa |  Nigeria NGA | 448120 | POLYGON ((26958.294 253210.950, 35554.540 4322..

I am not sure how to find the NEAREST distance between the coord points in my first dataframe to the nigeria shape border. I have tried using shapely i think but I keep getting 0 since the coordinates are inside of the polygon.

At the end result, I want to the distance from the coord point to the nearest distance to the boarder of Nigeria for all the rows in the first dataframe.

Thank you :)

Edit -- To include more info and  code
I saved the first dataset with the point coordinates as 'coord_new'

`df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(coord_new,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(coord_new.longitude, coord_new.latitude))`

`#df= df.to_crs(26392)`

`#nigeria = nigeria.to_crs(26392)`

`df['distance1']=nigeria.exterior.distance(df)`

`df['distance1']=nigeria.boundaries.distance(df)`

This is the way that I saw other people doing to find the distance from point to the border of the polygon. However, I keep getting 0 and then NaN in the distance1 column.

Comment: I don't get the question: there are infinite possible distances within a range from a point within the polygon to the edge of the polygon, right? I.e. the distance to the north border is different than the distance to the south, west, north-east, etc... borders. Do you want the smallest distance? The largest?

Comment: Hi Yes I want the smallest distance to the border. Thank you!

Comment: Alright. Can you [edit] your question to show what you searched for (and what you found) when you "*looked through the internet and stack overflow for days*"?

Comment: Hi I just edited! From what I looked at, most people try to find the distance between points (that are outside of the polygon) to the polygon. However, I am trying to find the distance of coordinate points that are inside the polygon to the edge of it.

Comment: This is more an algorithm question than a Python question. I googled articles and code about this problem.

Comment: According to the [distance docs](https://geopandas.org/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.distance.html) you don't need to refer to the boundary or exterior. You should be able to find the distance between a point and a polygon. However, the indexes of the two dataframes must be aligned: i.e. for each point in `df` there must be a polygon to which the distance can be calculated, perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: @Malo I'm not sure I follow? Why is it not a Python question, when the OP is trying to achieve this using Python tools?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is that when using [binary spatial operations](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geoseries.html#binary-predicates) or [distance](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.distance.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.distance) involving two GeoDataFrames, the DataFrames are aligned on their indexes.

Note the arguments to the [`GeoSeries.distance`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.distance.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.distance) function:

> Parameters:
>
> - **other**: ***Geoseries or geometric object***
>   The Geoseries (elementwise) or geometric object to find the distance to.

When you subset the global shapefile to only rows matching the name "Nigeria", you're still left with a GeoDataFrame, albeit one with only one row. The distance operation is therefore performed elementwise, where first `df` and `nigeria` are aligned on their indices, and then the elementwise distance is taken between rows in the two dataframes. Since there are no common indices between the two, the result is a column of `NaN`s.

This works the same way as in pandas - if you add two series with different indexes together, even if one of them is length 1, you would get `NaN` as a result.

On the other hand, if `nigeria` is a shapely geometry object rather than a GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame, there is no index to align on, and geopandas will compare each element in the dataframe to the geometry. The pandas analogue here is adding a constant to a `Series`, which results in a valid sum of each element with the constant.

So, you can change your code to select out the shapely geometry object, then compare it to each element in `df`:

```py
# use `.at` to extract the element instead of returning a length-1
# DataFrame. The result will be a shapely geometry.
nigeria = world.at[world['name'] == 'Nigeria', 'geometry']

type(nigeria)  # shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon

# compare each element in df to Nigeria's boundary
df['distance1'] = df.distance(nigeria.boundary)
```